# numpy.memmap to Image.frombuffer - without copying

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to memory map a file created in another process to use as a shared frame buffer.  I don't want the data copied because I want to use PIL ImageDraw functions to manipulate the mapped buffer, then flush the changes.  I'm fairly new to python and memory mapped files.  What am I missing?

```
# This is my setup code that creates a memory mapped array - seems to work
buf = np.memmap('/tmp/shared_mem', mode="readwrite", dtype="uint32", shape=(60,60))

# Here I build a PIL Image from the memory mapped data and correct layout, etc...
img = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (60, 60), buf)
dr = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# Changes using ImageDraw or putpixel do not show in the mapped file.
dr.rectangle(((0,0), (60,60)), fill="red")
buf.flush()

# Changes using numpy methods work just fine.
buf.fill(0)
buf.flush()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/Image.py#L2152) for `frombuffer`. Turns out it sets a `readonly` flag to `1`. I'm not sure about the side-effects, but if you set the flag to zero your code works:

```
buf = np.memmap(fname, mode="readwrite", dtype="uint32", shape=(n,n))
buf[:] = 0
img = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (n, n), buf)
img.readonly = 0
dr = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
dr.rectangle(((0,0), (n,n)), fill="red")
print buf[0,0]
# 4278190335
```

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed that last night but I didn't try forcing it.  Good to know...  I have it working with pysdl now.  More C code for better performance.